# SqlDependency - login failed error

Tags: sqldependency

I am trying to use `SqlDependency` to create a sample SignalR application. I am using the SQL admin account with sysadmin role. I am writing the following code:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    command.Notification = null;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
    SqlDependency.Start(connection.ConnectionString);
    //dependency.OnChange += dependency_OnChange;

    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
       connection.Open();

    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

The problem is that when the following line is executed,

```
SqlDependency.Start(connection.ConnectionString);
```

I get the error :

> Login failed for the user 'sa'

The same code works fine, when I comment it and load the data normally (without dependency). I am also able to login into the Management studio account, using these credentials.

Comment: Did you manage to find solution to this issue? I keep experiencing a similar thing.

Comment: Don't remember the exact solution but one possible solution out of the steps taken include, creating new user with admin permissions

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that that Connection object looses the password after you initialize connection. Add  Yourconnectionsting.PersistSecurityInfo = True

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your ConnectionString. It is in your web.config file and probably contains something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionStringName" connectionString="Data   Source=YourSqlServerName;Initial Catalog=YourDataBaseName;User ID=sa;Password=YourPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

After you receive this error I suppose that you use SQL Server Authentication, because for Windows authentication you dont have to specify User ID and pass. So what I can suggest you is to open Managment Studio and try to connect with settings from your ConnectionString: Server name, login - in your case "sa" and password. Probably problem is in your user/password.